# android release apk apksigner not able to verify jarsigner

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I see that ionic 2 documentation suggest to use `jarsigner` to sign the apk and `apksigner` to verify. The problem is that i am able to verify with `jarsigner`. But when i run the `apksigner` verify command nothing returns.

Does this means that my app is still signed?

Answer (score 0):

`apksigner` was designed to follow the UNIX command-line tool philosophy to not print anything out if everything is OK. This may be confusing when switching from `jarsigner` which does print "jar verified" when everything is OK.

You can pass in `-v` or `--verbose` to make `apksigner` print out information even when APK's signature verifies. You can also check the return code. It is `0` when everything is OK and non-zero otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow below  steps.
    1)  ionic build android --prod

```
2)  jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore 
C:\Users\admin_2\Desktop\keystore.dat 
D:\ionicv2\YOUR_PROJECT_NAME\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-
release-unsigned.apk YOUR_PROJECT_alias

3)  C:\Users\admin_2\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.2\zipalign -
v 4 
D:\ionicv2\YOUR_PROJECT_NAME\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-
release-unsigned.apk   
D:\ionicv2\YOUR_PROJECT_NAME\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\YOUR_APK_
LIVE_NAME.apk
```